# Pymongo MongoClient: if you put a database in via URI, how do you get it back out?

Tags: python, mongodb

The documentation for `MongoClient` says that one may say 'host=' and give a full MongoDB URI. Those include a database name. Once I do that, is there some way to extract the db name from the MongoClient object? I'm failing to spot it in the source code.

Comment: When I tried that I got a warning back from pymongo that the "database name in URI is being ignored."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for can be found in `pymongo.uri_parser`. In particular, look at the [parse_uri](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/uri_parser.html#pymongo.uri_parser.parse_uri) function. `parse_uri` takes a MongoDB URI as an argument and returns a dictionary containing values such as `username`, `password` and, most importantly, `database`.

Example:

```
from pymongo.uri_parser import parse_uri

mongo_uri = 'mongodb://james:brewer@localhost/test'

for k, v in parse_uri(mongo_uri).items():
    print k, ':', v
```

will print

```
username : james
nodelist : [('localhost', 27017)]
database : test
connection : None
password : brewer
options : {}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 6):

The `MongoClient` class has a [method called `get_default_database(default=None, [...other options...])`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html#pymongo.mongo_client.MongoClient.get_default_database) documented as:

> Get the database named in the MongoDB connection URI.

`MongoClient` also has a [method called `.get_database(name=None, [... other options...])`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html#pymongo.mongo_client.MongoClient.get_database) , where the `name=None` parameter is defined as:

> name (optional): The name of the database - a string. If None (the default) the database named in the MongoDB connection URI is returned.

So if all you have is the URI, but that URI contains a database name, You can get the MongoDB database like this:

```py
    mongo_database = pymongo.MongoClient(host=mongo_uri).get_default_database()
```

Or like this:

```py
    mongo_database = pymongo.MongoClient(host=mongo_uri).get_database()
```

The `default=` parameter in the first method above and the `name=` parameter in the second perform the same function: allowing the application programmer to override the database named in the URI, or supplement it if one was not provided in the URI.